# How do I translate a list using a dictionary in bash?

Tags: bash

Say I have a dictionary TSV file `dict.txt`:

```
apple     pomme
umbrella  parapluie
glass     verre
...       ...
```

and another file `list.txt` containing a list of words (from the left column of `dict.txt`):

```
pie
apple
blue
...
```

I'd like to translate them into the corresponding words from the right column of `dict.txt`, i.e:

```
tarte
pomme
bleu
...
```

what is the easiest way to do so?

Answer (score 6):

You can use awk:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} a[$1]{print a[$1]}' dict.txt list.txt
```

**EDIT:** If there is a requirement to have multi words (separated by spaces) as word meaning in the dictionary using tab se field separator you can use:

```
awk -F '\t' 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} a[$1]{print a[$1]}' dict.txt list.txt
```

Comment: @JS웃 Then downvoted my answer with the comment "`-1` for suggesting the wrong tool!". Please.

Comment: Though, this doesn't exactly fulfill the requirements of the OP, the OP has tab separated fields, so the pair `$'real value\tvaleur réelle'` is not going to be handled properly with this.

Comment: That's not correct, it very well works with tab separated fields. **Default field separator in awk is space or tab.**

Comment: @anubhava, did you actually understand my comment (because it seems you didn't). If in file `dict.txt` you have the line `real value\tvaleur réelle` (where `\t` is a tab) and if in file `words.txt` you have the line `real value`, your snippet will output `value` and not `valeur réelle` as expected.

Comment: 1. I didn't see requirement of multiple words with spaces in OP or examples. 2. A dictionary normally would contain a single word only. 3. If at all this is needed by OP then change is just an addition of `-F '\t'` in awk command as: `awk -F '\t' 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} a[$1]{print a[$1]}' dict.txt words.txt`

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I didn't downvote your answer. I usually down vote poorly written questions not answers.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have many words (so that everything fits in memory) you can use an associative array:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A english2french=()

# Build dictionary
linenb=0
while ((++linenb)) && IFS=$'\t' read -r en fr; do
    if [[ -z $fr ]] || [[ -z $en ]]; then
        echo "Error line $linenb: one of the two is empty fr=\`$fr' en=\`$en'"
        continue
    fi
    english2french["$en"]=$fr
done < dict.txt

# Translate
linenb=0
while ((++linenb)) && read -r en; do
    [[ -z $en ]] && continue
    fr=${english2french["$en"]}
    if [[ -n $fr ]]; then
        echo "$fr"
    else
        echo >&2 "Error line $linenb: word \`$en' unknown"
    fi
done < list.txt
```

It seems a bit long, but there are lots of error checks `;)`.